# mvc pattern in hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi

i'm trying to orgnize the a hapi folder i added the database also the route but i cant seem to find a way to add the controller , so how i can make it so i can use controller instead of adding all the code in the router
thank you so much

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: ""
    });
    
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });
    module.exports = con
```

Routes

```
"use strict";
const Path = require("path");

module.exports = [
{
    method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: (request, h) => {

            return 'Hello World!';
        }
}
];
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const Routes = require("./lib/routes");
const db = require('./config/db')
const init = async () => {

    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });
    server.route(Routes);
    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};
db.connect
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```